# .gitconfig: can I use %ProgramFiles(x86)% in the core.editor value?

Tags: git, mingw

git version 2.4.5.windows.1
MINGW64
Windows 7 x64

I try point an editor through three variants. First:

```
git config --global core.editor "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\""
```

At this case

```
git commit
```

works fine (notepad++ was opened), but I want to use the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` variable because I've roaming profile of Windows and other machines can have other `%SystemDrive%` value instead of `C:`.

Second vaiant:

```
git config --global core.editor "\"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\""
```

Third variant:

```
git config --global core.editor "\"$ProgramFiles(x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\""
```

But for both these cases

```
git commit
```

doesn't work (notepad++ wasn't opened). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to include the notepad++ path in your Windows Path string. Then you could just say

`git config --global core.editor notepad++`

Comment: Yes, I remember about this variant, but what about the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` using? Is it impossible? It is interesting for me.

Comment: The `%programfiles(x86)%` variable translates to the program files folder, and it includes the drive as well, so you only need to provide the rest of the path up to notepad++.  I will test it with git config and let you know.

Comment: The edited solution was not functioning properly in all console environments so I removed it